# sshpass and SU and command all together in one liner query

Tags: bash, su, sshpass

In my script:
1. I have to do ssh to a machine by username and password
2. Than I have to do Su - user, it prompts for password
3. Than I have to run my command i.e ls .

Earlier, There was no step2 and I was happily able to use sshpass & fire my queries through my script in a one liner command. something like this. 
sshpass -p pass user@host "command or ls"

But now I have one additional step of doing su after ssh. So Can someone please help me in understanding , how can I use all 3 together i.e sshpass, su and command in one line query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to change users for that one command, you need the "-c" flag.

```
su - user -c "[command]"
```

Nesting the quotes can get a little complicated, but in this case you just need to escape the inner ones.

```
su - user -c "sshpass -p pass user@host \"command or ls\""
```

Comment: I will explain how I do it manually. I am not sure if your solution work or not.
cmd1 : ssh hostname -l user 
it prompts me for the password. I enter it. 
hostname>  su - user 
It again prompts for the password.

then I run my command here , like ls. 

looks like you are first doing su and then sshpass, and your cmd have no place to enter the su password.

Comment: @TajinderSingh - why would a user need to su to himself? Remember `ssh -l user host` logs in as the user `user`.

Comment: Not to himself. 
Commands I run are 
1.  sshpass -p abc123 ssh alpha@tyco@company.com 
2.  su - beta and than enter password for this user beta *****
3.  than I run my actual command. forexample cat log.txt 

I first have to do ssh with use alpha, and than have to do su to user beta and than have to run command as beta. Is it possible in one liner ?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @TajinderSingh - what's stopping you from running `sshpass -p betapass beta@tyco.company.com`? Clearly you are running command as user `beta` but not as user `alpha` and user `beta` successively.

Comment: Approach1
step1:  I tried this sshpass -p betapass beta@tyco.company.com "command" 
I get error - "command"  command not found. 
Approach2
step1: But when I do this sshpass -p betapass beta@tyco.company.com
step2: [betauser@tyco.com ~]$  command
...... It works. 

Approach1 is not working and approach2 works, but I want something in one liner, because I want to run this one line command from my code. with in my code, I can't do this 2 steps process mentioned in approach2.

Comment: @TajinderSingh - The difference between your approaches is the environment, specifically the `PATH`. You can simply source the environment files of user `beta`. Try `sshpass -p betapass beta@tyco.company.com "source .bash_profile; command"`.

Comment: I tried it now andI got this ....... 
bash: command : permission denied. 

Looks like it tried to run , but doesn't have permission, any idea what I can do ? I think we are close :) 
Thanks